# JSON Deserializing

Tags: apex, rest-api, httprequest, apexrest

This is my updated class

```
public class ConvertCurrencyWS
{

public class ResponsWS
{

String id;
String quote;

}

public void getConvertCurrency()
{

Http h = new Http();

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndPoint('http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random');
req.setMethod('GET');

HttpResponse resp = h.send(req);
//return  resp.getBody();
String resstring = resp.getBody();
ResponsWS r = (ResponsWS)JSON.deserialize(resstring,ResponsWS.class);

System.debug('Response is '+resstring);
System.debug('The quote is '+r.Id+'   '+r.quote);



}


}
```

Q :

It works but the json serializing is not happening somehow as because the second debug returns as "null" for both the id & quote as shown below.

Can someone tell me why both the values are returning as null ?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a certificate issue for me pls make sure on this.

Comment: @SalesforceLearner You are right...I have found out that the particular API needs certificate...I am now trying with another API and have encountered another issue..can you see ?...I have updated the question now

Comment: Updated the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make your own class that you deserialize it into:

```
public class MyWebserviceResponse{

    public string type;
    public ValueClass value;

    public class ValueClass{
        public integer id;
        public string quote;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Martin...Thanks But even after deserializing I am getting null in the class's value...please take a look at my update

Comment: @ZenSeeker I think the problem is that the class variables are not visible when you are deserializing the JSON string. Try making them `public`.

Comment: Hmm..I tried them as public but still no luck :(

Comment: @ZenSeeker I figured it out, we need to have this as a subclass. I'll update my answer.